# Re-call an input outside a loop

Tags: loops, python-3.x

This is probably the most ugly code you'll ever see, anyway I need help, cause I didn't get it how loops works.
The idea of the script is easy, you put a name of a Superhero and you'll get his real name. Then if you want, you can choose the "biography" section, to get into details.

```
import sys
import os
super_heros = {'Hulk': 'Bruce Banner',                # Creo lista supereroei
               'Capitan America': 'Steve Rogers',
               'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker'}

hero_biography = {'Bruce Banner': 'David Banner nasce in California. '
                                   'Si laurea con il massimo dei voti in medicina, radiologia, genetica'
                                   'e biologia molecolare. '
                                   'A pochi anni dalla laurea, acquisisce una grande fama come medico in malattie'
                                   'rare e genetiche, nonché come ricercatore in ambito radiologico, cellulare, e '
                                   'atomico. '
                                   'Per anni insegna scienze genetiche a Princeton e a Stanford, dove acquisisce'
                                   'una fama sempre crescente nel campo delle ricerche sugli impulsi emotivi e '
                                   'sui raggi gamma. '
                                   'Le sue ricerche subiscono una grande ispirazione quando legge i primi articoli '
                                   'del dottorRonald Pratt, secondo il quale è possibile ottenere poteri guaritori '
                                   'da una manipolazione genetica. '
                                   'Al termine insegnamento come docente universitario, Banner lavora presso un '
                                   'laboratorio dove è affiancato da Elèna Marks, una vecchia compagna del college',
                  'Peter Parker' : 'Prova'}

print('Script creato da Federico Di Lembo')

while True:  # Loop per condizione soddisfatta

    choice = input('Nome Supereroe:')
    if choice == 'Hulk':
        print(super_heros['Hulk'])
    elif choice == 'Capitan America':
        print(super_heros['Capitan America'])
    elif choice == 'Spiderman':
        print(super_heros['Spiderman'])

    elif choice == 'Esc':  # Imposto uscita dal programma
        sys.exit(0)
    elif choice == 'Biografia':  # Imposto uscita dal loop
        break
    else:
        choice == ''
        print('Nome inesistente')

while True:  # Imposto Nuovo Loop per la seconda scelta
    x = 1
    if x > 0:
        newchoice = input('Biografia: digitare nome reale del supereroe ==> ')
    if newchoice == 'Bruce Banner':
        print(hero_biography['Bruce Banner'])
        break
    elif newchoice == 'Peter Parker':
        print(hero_biography['Peter Parker'])
    if newchoice == '':
        newchoice


while True:
    x = 1
    if x > 0:
        secondnewchoice = input('Desideri continuare la ricerca nella sezione Biografia?')

    if secondnewchoice == 'No':
        break
    if secondnewchoice == 'Si':
        newchoice



os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

In the last part of the code, I don't understand how to "recall" the newchoice input. 
In the last loop the question is "Would you like to stay in the biography section?", then if your answer is "yes" "Si", I want to refer to newchoiche input, just above. 
What I'm doing wrong?

I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while` loops don't start a new scope. `newchoice` is still visible and set after the loop where it is set completes.

```
while True:
    foo = 3
    break
print foo   # Outputs 3
```

Your problem appears to be that you aren't actually *doing* anything with `newchoice` in the last loop; it's a string-valued variable, not a function call. Perhaps you want a nested loop:

```
while True:  # Loop A
    while True:  # Loop B
        newchoice = input('Biografia: digitare nome reale del supereroe ==> ')
        if newchoice == '':
            break  # Exit loop B, moving on to loop C
        elif newchoice not in hero_biography:
            continue
        else:
            print(hero_biography[newchoice])

    while True:  # Loop C
        stay = input('Desideri ...')
        if stay in ("No", "Si"):
            break  # Exit loop C
    if stay == "No":
        break  # Exit loop A
```